# Need to learn how to use SQLCMD to export a query from SAP B1

Tags: sqlcmd, sapb1

I use SAP B1 at work and want to export a CSV file in a batch file so that I can schedule the export every 15 minutes to be uploaded to a website.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
SQLCMD -S SERVER-VMSQL -d SBO_COMPANYNAME -U sa -P adminpassword -Q "SELECT ItemCode, FrgnName, OnHand-IsCommited FROM OITM" -s "," -o "\\server-address\users\rick\TestBat.csv" -h-1 -s"," -W -w 999
```

This gives me an export of a CSV with the columns:

- Item Code
- Item Name
- Qty on hand less qty on sales orders

What I need is to elaborate on this query to put in some WHERE clauses - for example WHERE:

- U_Category = 'Toys' (where U_Category is a user defined field)
- Qrygroup2 = 'Y'

All of the above fields are within the OITM table.

Also - how do you join tables with SQLCMD queries?
I need to be able to join the OITW table to be able to specify in the WHERE clause that T1.[WhsCode] = '01. Main'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to prevent you from using `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses in the queries that you supply to SQLCMD. They're just regular SQL queries.

For example, here is the query you provided modified to include the restrictions you specified:

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode, OITM.FrgnName, OITM.OnHand-OITM.IsCommited
FROM OITM
   INNER JOIN OITW
       ON OITW.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode
WHERE OITM.U_Category = 'Toys'
    AND OITM.Qrygroup2 = 'Y'
    AND OITW.WhsCode = '01. Main'
```

You would just supply this query to SQLCMD, as you did with the query in your OP:

```
SQLCMD -S SERVER-VMSQL -d SBO_COMPANYNAME -U sa -P adminpassword -Q "SELECT OITM.ItemCode, OITM.FrgnName, OITM.OnHand-OITM.IsCommited FROM OITM INNER JOIN OITW ON OITW.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode WHERE OITM.U_Category = 'Toys' AND OITM.Qrygroup2 = 'Y' AND OITW.WhsCode = '01. Main'" -s "," -o "\\server-address\users\rick\TestBat.csv" -h-1 -s"," -W -w 999
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you're trying to do a little more?
I've written VB.NET code and made batch files to execute that code every x minutes with windows task scheduler.

You mention the OITM table, but there's also the ITM1 table to consider, I find that joining these two tables in the same query usually gives me everything I need (in terms of data) to apply the correct where clauses for validation.

Again, apologies for not fully understanding your problem but if you can elaborate on the issue a little more I'd be happy to do my best to help.

Cal.

Comment: Hi Cal, 
Sorry that it's taken so long to get to this.
Basically all I want to do is to export a CSV file from my SAP B1 SQL Databases with the information above.

The real issue is to pull in the on hand quantity and the committed quantity for a specific warehouse.